# Why do Spring Cloud Netflix applications deployed on Docker containers require explicitly setting eureka.instance.hostname?

Tags: spring, docker, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

A simple scenario:

- 2 eureka servers (http://archimedes1 http://archimedes2)
- 1 Config Server
- 1 Zull Gateway
- 1 Business Microservice

Deployed on localhost everything works as expected.

I dockerized them to run on individual containers for each app and tested on Docker over Windows.

What I see after deploying (config server, zull, and b-ms) is that if I dont specify `eureka.instance.hostname` for each of them **they register in the Eureka servers with an invalid URL**. This makes them impossible to call each other since they are getting invalid URLs.

For instance:

```
CONFIGSERVER    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - 287dd3ada410:configserver:8888
```

`287dd3ada410:configserver:8888` points at `287dd3ada410:8888/info`. And this doesn't exist.

To **work around** this I had to add to configserver's application.yml (and the equivalent for the other apps):

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: config-server
```

Now it shows up in eureka like this:

```
CONFIGSERVER    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - c99cdfe9bd01:configserver:8888
```

And `c99cdfe9bd01:configserver:8888` points at `http://config-server:8888/info`, which now resolves the config server correctly.

**Why is it necessary to use `eureka.instance.hostname` for each service? Why don't they register with their IP:port as when running without Docker (`c99cdfe9bd01:configserver:8888 -> 192.168.99.100:8888`) ?**

Answer (score 3):

I believe each Docker container would need to register using the Docker host IP and Docker host port mapped to the container port.

This what I have used:

Eureka instance:

```
docker run -idt -p 8001:8001 --net=host -e spring.profiles.active=peerAware -e appPort=8001 -e hostName=$HOSTNAME -e dataCenter=asimio-cloud-dal -e environment=staging -e peerUrls="http://$HOSTNAME:8002/eureka/" asimio/discovery-server:1.0.73
```

A service instance:

```
docker run -idt -p 8601:8601 --net=host -e appPort=8601 -e hostName=$HOSTNAME -e eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone="http://$HOSTNAME:8001/eureka/,http://$HOSTNAME:8002/eureka/" asimio/demo-registration-api-2:1.0.21
```

http://tech.asimio.net/2016/11/14/Microservices-Registration-and-Discovery-using-Spring-Cloud-Eureka-Ribbon-and-Feign.html#running-the-discovery-server-and-demo-services-in-docker-containers

Comment: The host name is automatically looked up using java.net.InetAddress.  If the address set in the docker container is not right than you will need to set it yourself.